# Split Textfile in PowerShell by line and string

Tags: powershell, logging, split, match

I know there are many questions about this topic that are awnsered alreade, but unfortunatly none that helped me in my case:
I have a server.log file looking like this:

```
################################################## 
ServerLog 07.07.2017  1:00:02,02 
Software Version 2.5 (modified 30.06.2017 15:53) 
################################################## 


Number of clients: 4 


KB-Server is online 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Client 1 

current client: \\192.168.0.22\Dauerversuch01 

Connecting the network share successfull? 
client connected successfully  

No files found 
---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Client 2 

current client: \\192.168.0.23\Dauerversuch01 

Connecting the network share successfull? 
client connected successfully  


3
Files found in the directory 

Copy from Client to local HDD: 
"\\192.168.0.23\Dauerversuch01 --> D:\Transfer" 
All files passed the md5 check 

Files won't get analysed by GlyphWorks 

copy files from hdd to server: 
"D:\Transfer --> \\mucs0244\Pool\CoC-AS\MessdatenQuantum\Dauerversuch_01_DUMMY\2017\07" 
All files passed the md5 check 

files were transfered successfully from the client to the server 


---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Client 3 

current client: \\192.168.0.24\Dauerversuch 

Connecting the network share successfull? 
client connected successfully  


3
Files found in the directory 

Copy from Client to local HDD: 
"\\192.168.0.24\Dauerversuch --> D:\Transfer" 
All files passed the md5 check 

Files won't get analysed by GlyphWorks 

copy files from hdd to server: 
"D:\Transfer --> \\mucs0244\Pool\CoC-AS\MessdatenQuantum\Dauerversuchspruefstand_02_SL20-4\2017\07" 
All files passed the md5 check 

files were transfered successfully from the client to the server 


---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Client 4 

current client: \\192.168.0.25\Dauerversuch01 

Connecting the network share successfull? 
client connected successfully  


3
Files found in the directory 

Copy from Client to local HDD: 
"\\192.168.0.25\Dauerversuch01 --> D:\Transfer" 
All files passed the md5 check 

Files won't get analysed by GlyphWorks 

copy files from hdd to server: 
"D:\Transfer --> \\mucs0244\Pool\CoC-AS\MessdatenQuantum\Dauerversuch_01_DUMMY2\2017\07" 
All files passed the md5 check 

files were transfered successfully from the client to the server 



---------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Batch erfolgreich beendet
```

You propably already guessed, I want to split the server.log into client logs. To be specific I want to be able to run my PowerShell script with a client number as input parameter, the script should then output eg. client2.log looking like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Client 2 

current client: \\192.168.0.23\Dauerversuch01 

Connecting the network share successfull? 
client connected successfully  


3
Files found in the directory 

Copy from Client to local HDD: 
"\\192.168.0.23\Dauerversuch01 --> D:\Transfer" 
All files passed the md5 check 

Files won't get analysed by GlyphWorks 

copy files from hdd to server: 
"D:\Transfer --> \\mucs0244\Pool\CoC-AS\MessdatenQuantum\Dauerversuch_01_DUMMY\2017\07" 
All files passed the md5 check 

files were transfered successfully from the client to the server 


---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The best I could do is this small script

```
$file = (GC H:\server.log)
foreach ($line in $file) {
  if ($line -match "^Client \w+") {
    $newfile = "$($line.Split(' ')[1]).txt"
  } else {
    $line | Out-File -Append $newfile
  }
}
```

But this does not work correctly and searching for the "----" lines does not work.

Comment: Maybe you should alter logging of that software you use to create these instead? Parsing freeform text files is a real pain.

Comment: Not really possible unfortunatly, but I could alter the software to lets say only include one "--------" line, but I have no Idea how to do it then either...

Comment: "(?s)(?=Client\s\d).*?(?=---)" should match the full block for a client. Then if i do not recall wrong the matches will be in the array (?) $match, loop through it and write out the log based on the first line in the match. _(probably some nicer way to write the regex)_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) for extracting the client sections from your server log to individual client log files:

```
$serverlog = 'H:\server.log'
$re = '(?ms)----+\r?\n(Client \d+)[\s\S]*?----+'

Select-String -Path $serverlog -Pattern $re -AllMatches |
    Select-Object -Expand Matches |
    ForEach-Object {
        $clientlog = 'C:\path\to\{0}.log' -f $_.Groups[1].Value
        $_.Groups[0].Value | Set-Content $clientlog
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided the clients number from 1 and are consecutive,
this script assumes logs to be in current folder:

```
$Splitter='-'*69
$ClientLogs =(Get-Content .\server.log -raw) -split "$Splitter`r?`n$Splitter"
For ($i=1; $i -lt $ClientLogs.Count-1; $i++){
   Set-Content -Path (".\Client_$i.log") -Value $ClientLogs[$i]
}
```